# VSCode C#, 2nd Project has no IntelliSense and Code Formatting

Tags: visual-studio-code, c#-7.0, omnisharp

I'm currently reading Mark J. Prices' Book. But I came across a problem where I cannot find the OmniSharp: Select Project when finding it in the View | Command Palette. I guessed that's where the issue came from, the issue of IntelliSense not working and Code Format and Keywords are all just sky blue.[Screenshot of 2nd project having no format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHPR8.png)

[Screenshot of the first project working just fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cGKZ.png)

I tried ChatGPT suggestions but they don't seem to work. Restarting VSCode does not work. And the other options may not seem to work because I find it out of scope.